# What is the difference between 'with open(...)' and 'with closing(open(...))'

Tags: python

From my understanding,

```
with open(...) as x:
```

is supposed to close the file once the `with` statement completed. However, now I see

```
with closing(open(...)) as x:
```

in one place, looked around and figured out, that `closing` is supposed to close the file upon finish of the `with` statement.

So, what's the difference between closing the file and `closing` the file?

Comment: What was the "one place" for `closing`? That doesn't seem like a built-in thing. The point of opening with `with` is exactly that the file is closed *no matter what*.

Comment: @AndrasDeak You can see it in the Python documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/contextlib.html

Comment: `contextlib.closing` is not needed in this case.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming that's `contextlib.closing` and the standard, built-in `open`, `closing` is redundant here. It's a wrapper to allow you to use `with` statements with objects that have a `close` method, but don't support use as context managers. Since the file objects returned by `open` are context managers, `closing` is unneeded.